# Using custom theme in makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have done some research and was not able to find a solution.

I am trying to create a theme using createMuiTheme and use it later in makeStyles to retrieve the keys inside. (palette in the example) However it seems that the custom theme does not get applied in makeStyles.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { makeStyles, createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import red from "@material-ui/core/colors/red";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  console.log(theme); // Only defaults but not red in palette.
  return {
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.primary[400] // This is not working.
    }
  };
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: red
    }
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

However in another component using useTheme it works without any issue. What have I done wrong?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  console.log(theme); // Here palette includes the new palette.
  return {
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.primary[400]
    }
  };
});

function anotherApp() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme(); 
  ...
}
```

Comment: What about initializing the theme constant outside the function? I believe this is the convention I have used.

Comment: I think I have tried altering the order/scope but none worked. Some of the examples in official docs follow this approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your custom theme is applied in this line:     `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>`, and your makeStyles function is called before that. 
That means, in this line `const classes = useStyles();` you call your `makeStyles` function, but your theme is still the default theme. 
The solution is what you already did, create a `CustomizedButton` and inside it call the useStyles hook.

Comment: Does that mean it is not possible to create and use theme in the same component?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, maybe someone else can think of a way of how to do that. Anyway, this shouldn't be too much of an issue, since you should have only one ThemeProvider defined at the top of your app hierarchy.